# Bluetooth cant receive proper data

Tags: android, bluetooth

im sending data like **"52 40 00 00 CF E6 2A 1 2A 0 0 0 1 0 5 2A 0 0 0 0 2A 0 0 0 0 0 3B 00"** from HC-05. but the problem is when i reciving data i get different data.
device connected properly, but when i sending data to mobile device im getting wrong data.plaese help me.

here is my code what i did wrong?

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button btnSubmit, nextPage;
TextView txtArduino, txtString, txtStringLength, txtOutput, lblmeterId;
EditText txtMeterId, txtCommandNo;
Spinner txtCommandType;
Handler bluetoothIn;


StringBuilder packetFormat;
String packetRequest;

long packetFormatArray[] = new long[28];
long receivedDataArray[] = new long[28];

final int handlerState = 0;  //used to identify handler message
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
private StringBuilder recDataString = new StringBuilder();

private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

private static final UUID BTMODULEUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

// String for MAC address
private static String address;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

    nextPage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextPage);
    txtString = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtString);
    txtStringLength = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testView1);
    lblmeterId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblmeterId);

    txtOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOutput);
    txtMeterId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMeterId);
    txtCommandNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCommandNo);
    txtCommandType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.txtCommandType);


    bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {

            if (msg.what == handlerState) {       

                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

                receivedDataArray = BytesTrans.bytes2HexString(readBuf, msg.arg1);

                StringBuilder RpacketFormat = new StringBuilder();
                for (long value : receivedDataArray) {
                    RpacketFormat.append(value + " ");
                }

                String dataReceived = RpacketFormat.toString();
                int dataLength = dataReceived.length();
                txtString.setText("Received from Bluetooth: " + dataReceived);

                if (receivedDataArray[0] == 82  && receivedDataArray[1] == 64) {

                    //find meterId from string
                    StringBuilder rMid = new StringBuilder();
                    String rMeterId = "";
                    for (int i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
                        String hex = Integer.toHexString((int) (receivedDataArray[i] & 0xFF));
                        rMid.append(hex);
                        rMeterId = String.valueOf(rMid);
                    }
                    rMeterId = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(rMeterId, 16));
                    lblmeterId.setText("Received from Bluetooth: " + rMeterId);

                    //find command no from string
                    StringBuilder cId = new StringBuilder();
                    String cmdId = "";
                    cId.append(receivedDataArray[7]);
                    cmdId = String.valueOf(cId);
                    //cmdId= String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(cmdId,16));

                    //find kilo liters from String
                    StringBuilder kId = new StringBuilder();
                    String kiloLiters = "";
                    for (int i = 9; i <= 12; i++) {
                        kId.append(receivedDataArray[i]);
                        kiloLiters = String.valueOf(kId);
                        //kiloLiters = kiloLiters.replace("0","");
                    }
                    kiloLiters = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(kiloLiters, 16));

                    //find kilo liters from String
                    StringBuilder lId = new StringBuilder();
                    String liters = "";
                    for (int i = 13; i <= 14; i++) {
                        lId.append(receivedDataArray[i]);
                        liters = String.valueOf(lId);
                        //liters = liters.replace("0","");
                    }
                    liters = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(liters, 16));

                    //find I data liters from String
                    StringBuilder iId = new StringBuilder();
                    String idata = "";
                    for (int i = 16; i <= 17; i++) {
                        iId.append(receivedDataArray[i]);
                        idata = String.valueOf(iId);
                        //idata = idata.replace("0","");
                    }
                    idata = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(idata, 16));

                    //find F data liters from String
                    StringBuilder fId = new StringBuilder();
                    String fdata = "";
                    for (int i = 18; i <= 19; i++) {
                        fId.append(receivedDataArray[i]);
                        fdata = String.valueOf(fId);
                        //fdata = fdata.replace("0","");
                    }
                    fdata = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(fdata, 16));

                    //find flag1 from string
                    StringBuilder f1Id = new StringBuilder();
                    String flag1 = "";
                    f1Id.append(receivedDataArray[21]);
                    flag1 = String.valueOf(f1Id);
                    cmdId = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(flag1, 16));

                    //find flag2 from string
                    StringBuilder f2Id = new StringBuilder();
                    String flag2 = "";
                    f2Id.append(receivedDataArray[22]);
                    flag2 = String.valueOf(f2Id);
                    flag2 = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(flag2, 16));

                    //find flag3 from string
                    StringBuilder f3Id = new StringBuilder();
                    String flag3 = "";
                    f3Id.append(receivedDataArray[23]);
                    flag3 = String.valueOf(f3Id);
                    flag3 = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(flag3, 16));

                    //find flag4 from string
                    StringBuilder f4Id = new StringBuilder();
                    String flag4 = "";
                    f4Id.append(receivedDataArray[24]);
                    flag4 = String.valueOf(f4Id);
                    flag4 = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(flag4, 16));

                    //find flag5 from string
                    StringBuilder f5Id = new StringBuilder();
                    String flag5 = "";
                    f5Id.append(receivedDataArray[25]);
                    flag5 = String.valueOf(f5Id);
                    flag5 = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(flag5, 16));

                    recDataString.delete(0, recDataString.length()); //clear all string data

                    Intent receivedData = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayDate.class);

                    receivedData.putExtra("meterId", rMeterId);
                    receivedData.putExtra("cmdId", cmdId);
                    receivedData.putExtra("kiloLiters", kiloLiters);
                    receivedData.putExtra("liters", liters);
                    receivedData.putExtra("idata", idata);
                    receivedData.putExtra("fdata", fdata);
                    receivedData.putExtra("flag1", flag1);
                    receivedData.putExtra("flag2", flag2);
                    receivedData.putExtra("flag3", flag3);
                    receivedData.putExtra("flag4", flag4);
                    receivedData.putExtra("flag5", flag5);
                    receivedData.putExtra("dataReceived", dataReceived);
                    startActivity(receivedData);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please Try Again. not getting proper data. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    packetFormat = new StringBuilder();
                    for (long value : receivedDataArray) {
                        packetFormat.append(value + " ");
                    }
                    packetRequest = packetFormat.toString();
                    lblmeterId.setText("Received Data: " + packetRequest);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();       // get Bluetooth adapter
    checkBTState();
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
}

private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {

    return device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BTMODULEUUID);
    //creates secure outgoing connecetion with BT device using UUID
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //Get MAC address from DeviceListActivity via intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    //Get the MAC address from the DeviceListActivty via EXTRA
    address = intent.getStringExtra(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);

    //create device and set the MAC address
    if (address != null) {
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

        try {
            btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // Establish the Bluetooth socket connection.
        try {
            btSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                //insert code to deal with this
            }
        }
    }
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
    mConnectedThread.start();

    //I send a character when resuming.beginning transmission to check device is connected
    //If it is not an exception will be thrown in the write method and finish() will be called
    // mConnectedThread.write("Hi Im Connected.");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try {
        //Don't leave Bluetooth sockets open when leaving activity
        btSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        //insert code to deal with this
    }
}

//Checks that the Android device Bluetooth is available and prompts to be turned on if off
private void checkBTState() {

    if (btAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Device does not support bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        } else {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
        }
    }
}

//create new class for connect thread
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    //creation of the connect thread
    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        try {
            //Create I/O streams for connection
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }


    public void run() {


        byte[] buffer = new byte[29];
        int bytes;
        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void write(long[] packetFormatArray) {
        //converts entered String into bytes
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < packetFormatArray.length; i++) {
                int msgBuffer = (int) packetFormatArray[i];
                mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();

        }
    }
}
```

}

here it is

```
 public class BytesTrans {
public static long[] bytes2HexString(byte[] b, int count) {
    long  receivedData[] =  new long[29];
    String ret = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        String hex = Integer.toHexString(b[i] & 0xFF);
        if (hex.length() ==1) {
            hex = '0' + hex;
        }
        String capsHex= hex.toUpperCase();

        receivedData[i] = Long.parseLong(capsHex,16);

        ret += hex.toUpperCase() + " ";
    }
    return receivedData;
}
```

}

Comment: Well what are you receiving instead?

Comment: `"52 40 00 00 CF E6 2A 1 2A 0 0 0 1 0 5 2A 0 0 0 0 2A 0 0 0 0 0 3B 00" `. How many bytes would have been sent for this?

Comment: `long receivedDataArray[] = new long[28];`. AND `receivedDataArray = BytesTrans.bytes2HexString(readBuf, msg.arg1);`. ???? Why would a function called bytes2HexString return a long array. Does not make sense. Just convert the bytes to a hex string and tell us what you got.

Comment: im sending decimal equivalent of hex, so i need to convert it inti hex thats why i used receivedDataArray = BytesTrans.bytes2HexString(readBuf, msg.arg1)

Comment: sometimes i receive only 0 sometimes random no from the above data.

Comment: hey i find something.when i send data to mobile if i add 0 before my data then it works correctly.if i remove that 0 then it is not working.now what i do i dont want to add that 0 before my data.. is there any wrong in my loop while reading data?? @greenapps

Comment: You have not seriously explained bytes2HexString().

Comment: im sending data "82 64 00 00 207 230 42 01 42 00 00 00 01 00 05 42 00 00 00 00 42 00 00 00 00 00 59 00" it is  decimal equivlent value i need to convert it into hex thats why i used bytes2HexString function.  here is the function.

Comment: public static long[] bytes2HexString(byte[] b, int count) {
        long  receivedData[] =  new long[29];
        String ret = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(b[i] & 0xFF);
            if (hex.length() ==1) {
                hex = '0' + hex;
            }
            String capsHex= hex.toUpperCase();

            receivedData[i] = Long.parseLong(capsHex,16);

            ret += hex.toUpperCase() + " ";
        }
        return receivedData;
    }

Comment: now the problem is when I send "82 64 00 00 207 230 42 01 42 00 00 00 01 00 05 42 00 00 00 00 42 00 00 00 00 00 59 00" to bluetooth i didnt get this data, but when i add 0, means "00 82 64 00 00 207 230 42 01 42 00 00 00 01 00 05 42 00 00 00 00 42 00 00 00 00 00 59 00" it works perfectly. so is there any problen while reading data??

Comment: Well you say you send an extra 0. But do you receive that 0 too? Please put that code in your post as it is unreadable in comments.

Comment: ok. check it. actually what is happening, when i send data to device something going wrong here         public void run() {

            int bytes;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[29];
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                    bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, 0, buffer).sendToTarget();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

Comment: when data came it devide into two,1st it takes only first byte means if my data is  "82 64 00 00 207 230 42 01 42 00 00 00 01 00 05 42 00 00 00 00 42 00 00 00 00 00 59 00" it take 82 and rest of will be 0,  2nd it takes 64 00 00 207 230 42 01 42 00 00 00 01 00 05 42 00 00 00 00 42 00 00 00 00 00 59 00.  why it read two time and braks it.? why it looping two times?

Comment: Normal TCP behaviour. You should make a loop there and check the value of int bytes and sum it up until you received 29 bytes.

Comment: can u please write code here.

Comment: You should give it a try yourself. Then post the code. Not in a comment! Then we will have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the code

```
      public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[28];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes=0
 while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                // Get number of bytes and message in "buffer"
                for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read();
                    receivedDataArray[i] = bytes;
                }
                long abc[] = receivedDataArray;
                bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, receivedDataArray).sendToTarget();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
```